# AppleScript: keystroke 125 (down key) on Mavericks

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks

In Mac Lion: choose lock screen in lockscreen icon (Keychain Access -> Preferences --> General -> Show keychain ...), it will in screen saver mode.

In mavericks: when lock screen by above steps, it is NOT in screen saver mode. So we can not control it. I don't know why???

Then in locked screen, I tranfer event to press down key On MAVERICKS (It's OK on Mac Lion), but it seems not know about that:

```
 on run
      tell application "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app" to quit
      tell application "System Events" to key code 125
      delay 1
      tell application "System Events" to keystroke "password"
      delay 1
      tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
      delay 5
 end run
```

Excute above script by:

```
    NSString *source = [NSString stringWithFormat:kAppleScriptUnlockWithPassword ,password];

    // Create unlock script with password
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
    NSDictionary * errDic = nil;
    // Execute script
    [screenState removeAllObjects];
    [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errDic];

    NSLog(@"%@", errDic);
```

It returns:

```
{
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "System Events";
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Can\U2019t make {1, \"\"} into type text.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "System Events got an error: Can\U2019t make {1, \"\"} into type text.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1700";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {92, 20}";
}
```

Do you have any idea about it?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error ? For me its working fine. (screen saver is active)

Comment: I was update description, please help me check it again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`keystroke 125` inserts 125 as text. Try using `key code` instead:

```
quit application "ScreenSaverEngine"
tell application "System Events"
    key code 125
    delay 1
    keystroke "password" & return
end tell
```